# SharePoint Designer OOB Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

As per my project requirement, we have multiple departments having sub site.
One department user upload the document & approval workflow will be fired.It create task & assign to some User or group which is from another department.

My question is how to access the task generated by one department User (sub site i.e. (HR) ) which will also access by  another department's user ( sub site  i.e. (Account))

Is is possible ?

If not then please give me another option how to fire  document approval workflow within inter department.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can create different groups for different department and break the permission for Task list and give contribute rights to other permission groups...in this way other users can access the task list..

Comment: but when one department user upload document & assign to another department user that user don't have permission at that time to access the site where document is uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think you issue is 2-folded: > creating a new approval task while granting permissions to both the Approval Task (Contribute)  and the Document (at least Read). As consequence this would mean breaking security inheritance - across sub-sites - just using Security Groups will not suffice, unless you don't care that the other members of certain groups will get same access as the actual "Approver" to the file, even though they have no interest in it.

These being said, alternatives would be:

- Nintex - does this very easy (an option exists on the actual Approval
  task to change security on both the item and task ) - i assume this
  is not an option, right?
- Create another reusable workflow, running on the Content type (make sure also your Documents are custom content types to allow for easier attaching the actual workflows only to these content types, across all sub-sites) that uses the Assigned To property to change permissions.
- [Coding required] Have an Event handler running on the Approval task content type or
  List to set appropriate permissions as soon as Assigned To is changed and not empty - also go for the actual target Document (using the Related Content property, added automatically by the actual Workflow).